# e.preventDefault() is not working for submit button and anchor tag in MVC

Tags: javascript, typescript, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.Net Core MVC App

**View**

```
<form>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control small" asp-for="UserName" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control small" asp-for="Password" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-success pull-right" asp-action="Validate" asp-controller="LogIn" onclick="ValidateLogin()">Log In</a>
                <input type="submit" value="LogIn" asp-action="Validate" asp-controller="LogIn" onclick="ValidateLogin(this)" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**TypeScript Code**

```
   function ValidateLogin(e:Event) {
    var username = (document.getElementById('UserName') as HTMLInputElement).value;
    var password = (document.getElementById('UserName') as HTMLInputElement).value;
    if ((username.length > 0) && (password.length > 0)) {

    }
    else {
        alert('Fields required');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

If fields are empty than it should terminate the request , but it only display alert and e,preventDefault() is ineffective here .

I also tried return false , but nothing seems to work here . It should not go to action  method after preventDefault or return false statement

Can somebody tell me what am i missing here in this very simple task ?

**Update 1**

If i change the code in below way , than it works

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function (e) {
var username = (document.getElementById('UserName') as HTMLInputElement).value;
var password = (document.getElementById('UserName') as HTMLInputElement).value;
if ((username.length > 0) && (password.length > 0)) {

}
else {
    alert('Fields required');
    return false;
}
```

}

Still i dont know why it is not working when i wrap it in a method instead of calling directly with .onclick()

Comment: It's not ideal to handle form submission on `onclick` event, you should bind to form `onsubmit`. otherwise you will miss validation when users press enter on any input

Comment: Ok , first of all onsubmit even is not working and second i have to handle something else on button click , not validation , this is just to create a scenario

Comment: Who uses TypeScript, and then does “old-school” event handling via HTML on*-attributes …?

Comment: well its me , but if you have any suggestion to replace that code  than please ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I also tried return false , but nothing seems to work here . It should not go to action method after preventDefault or return false statement

As [kemicofa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54516106/10091607) points out, your `ValidateLogin`function expects an `Event` as a parameter. But you passed a `this`.

Let's inspect your code :

```
<input type="submit" value="LogIn" asp-action="Validate" asp-controller="LogIn" onclick="ValidateLogin(this)" />
```

Here the `ValidateLogin(this)` means you're telling the browser to pass this `input` DOM element to `ValidateLogin()`function as a parameter. As `Input` element has no `preventDefault` method, it fails.

> Still i dont know why it is not working when i wrap it in a method instead of calling directly with `.onclick()`

In short, here the **`this` references the DOM element which is the one that we attach the event handler to**. Anyway, `this` is not a instance of `Event`.

If you prefer to binding event handler with the `on{eventtype}="script_code"` HTML attribute, you could use the `event` variable:

```
    onclick="ValidateLogin(this)"

    onclick="ValidateLogin(event)"
```

because the `event` could be treated as a pre-defined local variable for your `script_code`. For more details, see [Registering on-event handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#Registering_on-event_handlers)

Both invoking by setting `.onclick=function(event){/**/};` from JavaScript and invoking `ValidateLogin(event)` with a inline HTML attribute should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
onclick="ValidateLogin(this)"
```

Your problem is your ValidateLogin method. You pass the "this" context and your method expects an event parameter.

Do this instead.

```
<form onsubmit="ValidateLogin()">
```

Remove the `onlclick` from your submit button.

Comment: @Saurabh did you see update by adding the onsubmit to your form?

Comment: Submit should send the event